# SimpleXML RSS help

Tags: php, foreach, simplexml

I'm trying to use SimpleXML to read our News RSS feed but it's not outputting anything.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://news.stanford.edu/rss/index.xml');
?>
<h1><?php echo $rss->title; ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($rss->item as $e) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"".$e->link['href']."\">";
    echo $e->title;     
    echo "</a></li>\n";
}    
?>
```

Comment: anything in your error_log? what happens if you `var_dump($rss)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that in the XML, everything is inside a channel tag. Also, your link doesn't want the ['href'] bit.

```
<?php
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://news.stanford.edu/rss/index.xml');
?>
<h1><?php echo $rss->channel->title; ?></h1>
<ul>
<?php

foreach($rss->channel->item as $chan) {  
        echo "<li><a href=\"".$chan->link."\">";
        echo $chan->title;     
        echo "</a></li>\n";
}  
?>
```

Here is [a link to the documentation for that function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've read through that documentation several times. After trying your code I'm still not getting anything from the h1 when I use that tag. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I was a little hastey with my first answer, here is some working code for you.

Comment: that works perfectly. Much simpler than other methods I found online. Thank you!